# integration by parts in academic paper that incorporates a discontinity

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, calculus-of-variations

Confused about these derivations from the appendix page 15 of paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11071-019-05117-z

bit I can't follow is in the picture here:

[image: int by parts]

dot denotes differentiation w.r.t to $t$ and dash denotes differentiation w.r.t to $s$ (arc length).

Says by using by parts, but the first derivation is for a multivariable function so it is a bit different? Tried to use standard by parts but can't seem to get anywhere.

Also, the presence of a discontinuity in the system complicates the integrals more denoted by the $\xi$ terms. Thanks very much.

Comment: The second integral does integration by parts, then proceeds to break down $\int_0^\ell fg\,ds$ into some formula apparently developed with information not included in your snippet. In the first integral, the differentiation is with respect to a different variable, so it doesn't qualify as "integration by parts". The similar looking start is just applying the differentiation product formula to modify the integrand. Then the differentiation and integration are exchanged. This exchange is not always justifiable with no change. Apparently in this case the last term measures the difference.